# how to insert tab delimited file into mysql with relation

Tags: mysql

What i want is to insert data in mysql table but i unable to find the way to make relationship from one row

suppose i have a file **file.tab** it contains data in like

```
parent_1    parent_details_1    child_1.1   child_details_1.1   child_1.2   child_details_1.2
parent_2    parent_details_2    child_2.1   child_details_2.1
parent_3    parent_details_3    child_3.1   child_details_3.1   child_3.2   child_details_3.2   child_3.3   child_details_3.3
```

what i want to achive is to insert data in two table like

```
            parent_table
+---+-----------+-------------------+
|id |   name    |      details      |
+---+-----------+-------------------+
| 1 |  parent_1 |  parent_details_1 |
| 2 |  parent_2 |  parent_details_2 |
| 3 |  parent_3 |  parent_details_3 |
+---+-----------+-------------------+


              child_table
+---+-----+-----------+-------------------+
|id | pid |   name    |      details      |
+---+-----+-----------+-------------------+
| 1 |  1  | child_1.1 | child_details_1.1 |
| 2 |  1  | child_1.2 | child_details_1.2 |
| 3 |  2  | child_2.1 | child_details_2.1 |
| 4 |  3  | child_3.1 | child_details_3.1 |
| 5 |  3  | child_3.2 | child_details_3.2 |
| 6 |  3  | child_3.3 | child_details_3.3 |
+---+-----+-----------+-------------------+
```

first two columns is for parent and after that two-two columns belongs to child but i don't know how many child a parent has.

i have tried to load file that way.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/file.tab INTO TABLE ...
```

but what do i do next i have no idea.

so kindly help me out in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a table (`Staging`) with lots of columns.  Have empty (`NULL`) columns for `parent_id` and ids for the children.

Hope that the 'short' lines will put nulls in the missing children columns during the `LOAD DATA`.

`INSERT .. SELECT ..` to get the `parent` and `parent_detail` into the `Parents` table.  Pull back the `ids` from `Parents` into `Staging.parent_id`.  The details on the two SQLs for these are in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization

Now do something similar for each possible "child" set of columns:  `child1` and `child1_detail` (possibly NULL pair) and the currently NULL `child1_id`.  Ditto for child2*, etc.  Note that when populating the `Children` table, you already have `parent_id` available.

This is an all-SQL way of doing the task.  It is only slightly less messy than writing Perl/PHP/Java/VB/whatever code to do the task.

Comment: As @RickJames says in the last sentence, it's an all-SQL way that is slightly less messy.  I think you'd be better off doing some sort of normalization outside of SQL which would be quite easy.  You could use a simple search where a newline is added after every 2 TABS.  Then you can grep for `parent` or `child` (presuming you have some way to ID the 2) so that you know whether to `INSERT` into the `parent` or `child` table.  IMHO, it does not seem worth doing all in 1 language, especiall if the file is as regular as you show (every 2 TABS is a new item).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both Children and Parents are a Person I'd create a Person table only with the id_parent being optional.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  details varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_parent1 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_parent2 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

How you load the data very much depends on your favourite language. `Load data infile` requires a static result table.

The number of rows you have can differ and you would need to pretty much import each row as a single column. You could then use a stored procedure to iterate over it:

- Look at `cursors` to see how to iterate over each row of such a single column staging table.
- Using `replace` on the tab delimiter you could figure out the number of columns in each row.
- Using the `while` loop you could then start to import the children first and then the parents.

In all fairness, this would be a fairly complex stored procedure and for a beginner probably quite hard to write. If you are familiar with any programming language and its means of connecting to MySQL you probably can do this much more elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution doesn't need to be all in SQL I find that preprocessing is often simpler.  In this case split data into two files that can be trivially loaded with LOAD DATA INFILE (one for the parent table and one for the child table).

Here is one way to do the preprocessing using perl

```
my ( $parent_id, $child_id ) = ( 0, 0 );
my ( @parent_table, @child_table );
while (<>) {                    # for each line of input
  chomp;
  # split on tabs
  my ( $parent_name, $parent_detail, @child_id_detail_pairs ) = split /\t/;
  # create a row and parent_id for the parent table
  push @parent_table, [ ++$parent_id, $parent_name, $parent_detail ];

  while (@child_id_detail_pairs) { # while we have child names & details
    # remove a name and details
    my $child_name    = shift @child_id_detail_pairs;
    my $child_details = shift @child_id_detail_pairs;

    # create a row and child_id for the child table
    push @child_table, [ ++$child_id, $parent_id, $child_name, $child_details ];
  }
}

# write this to one file to load into the parent table
print "parent_table\n";
for my $row (@parent_table) {
  print join( "\t", @$row ), "\n";
}

# write this to one file to load into the child table
print "child_table\n";
for my $row (@child_table) {
  print join( "\t", @$row ), "\n";
}
```

Comment: file is vary huge around 20 to 25 GB does it handle or won't take much time.

Comment: @User97798 as written this puts the entire file in memory before printing. Depending on how much memory you have that may not be ideal. However, the script could easily be modified to output a row at a time. Then memory wouldn’t be an issue. This should be reasonably performant, at least for a one-off. Even if you do it often I would test it and only optimize if necessary.