# How to insert data from staging to multiple table with mapping

Tags: mysql, denormalization

What i want is to insert data in mysql table but i unable to find the way to make relationship from one row

i have a staging table which has data like :

```
            staging_table
+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+
|  p_name   |      p_details    |  child_1  |  child_details_1  |  child_2  |  child_details_2  |  child_3  |  child_details_3  |
+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+
|  parent_1 |  parent_details_1 | child_1.1 | child_details_1.1 | child_1.2 | child_details_1.2 |           |                   |
|  parent_2 |  parent_details_2 | child_2.1 | child_details_2.1 |           |                   |           |                   |
|  parent_3 |  parent_details_3 | child_3.1 | child_details_3.1 | child_3.2 | child_details_3.2 | child_3.3 | child_details_3.3 |
+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+
```

what i want to achive is to insert data in two table like

```
            parent_table
+---+-----------+-------------------+
|id |   name    |      details      |
+---+-----------+-------------------+
| 1 |  parent_1 |  parent_details_1 |
| 2 |  parent_2 |  parent_details_2 |
| 3 |  parent_3 |  parent_details_3 |
+---+-----------+-------------------+


              child_table
+---+-----+-----------+-------------------+
|id | pid |   name    |      details      |
+---+-----+-----------+-------------------+
| 1 |  1  | child_1.1 | child_details_1.1 |
| 2 |  1  | child_1.2 | child_details_1.2 |
| 3 |  2  | child_2.1 | child_details_2.1 |
| 4 |  3  | child_3.1 | child_details_3.1 |
| 5 |  3  | child_3.2 | child_details_3.2 |
| 6 |  3  | child_3.3 | child_details_3.3 |
+---+-----+-----------+-------------------+
```

first two columns is for parent and after that two-two columns belongs to child. so i have to insert child data in child table but if it only insert data if columns has value not on null.

i have tried. `if` statement for this but unable to make relationship

but what do i do next i have no idea.

Comment: Adjacency List Model isn't really a great design to store hierarchical data in a database.. Nested Set Model or Closure Table should be your design.

Comment: yes you are right but the data which i have in staging table it loaded from a tab delimited file, please have a look in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471059/how-to-insert-tab-delimited-file-into-mysql-with-relation/47612245

Answer (score 0):

It should be obvious how to populate your parent table:

```
INSERT INTO parent_table (name, details)  
SELECT p_name name, p_details details FROM staging_table;
```

The child table you can create the same way, but doing unions of the three pairs of columns

```
INSERT INTO child_table (pid, name, details)
SELECT p.id pid, child_1 name, child_details_1 details
  FROM staging_table s
  JOIN parent_table p ON s.p_name = p.name AND s.p_details = p.details
 WHERE child_1 IS NOT NULL 
   AND child_details_1 IS NOT NULL

 UNION ALL

SELECT p.id pid, child_2 name, child_details_2 details
  FROM staging_table s
  JOIN parent_table p ON s.p_name = p.name AND s.p_details = p.details
 WHERE child_2 IS NOT NULL 
   AND child_details_2 IS NOT NULL

 UNION ALL

SELECT p.id pid, child_3 name, child_details_3 details
  FROM staging_table s
  JOIN parent_table p ON s.p_name = p.name AND s.p_details = p.details
 WHERE child_3 IS NOT NULL 
   AND child_details_3 IS NOT NULL;
```

See the three repeating parts of the query?  That's how you handle your denormalized input table.

See the `JOIN ... ON ..` clauses? That's how you handle getting your `pid` values into your child_table.

**I haven't debugged this.**